# SAS code to calculative Percent Difference

Tags: sas

I am dealing with a "long" dataset which contains numerous entries for various blood measures. I would like to be able to calculate the %difference for each new LDL level relative to the first reading for LDL.

I was successful at creating a start_dt variable that gets kept for each successive observation, but I can't figure out how to add a "start_LDL" level so that within each row, I can then calculate the %difference between the newest entry and the first entry.

Here is a sample of the dataset (clearly, there are a lot of missings (.) that just look like black spaces):

```
id  ldl  lab_dt     start_dt    diff_ldl    VISIT
1       17Oct2001   17Oct2001                 1
1       17Oct2001   17Oct2001                 2
1   173 17Oct2001   17Oct2001                 3
1       20Oct2006   17Oct2001                 4
1       20Oct2006   17Oct2001                 5
1       20Oct2006   17Oct2001                 6
1   165 20Oct2006   17Oct2001                 7
2       06Jul2000   06Jul2000                 1
2       06Jul2000   06Jul2000                 2
2       06Jul2000   06Jul2000                 3
2   166 06Jul2000   06Jul2000                 4
2       09Jan2001   06Jul2000                 5
2       09Jan2001   06Jul2000                 6
2       09Jan2001   06Jul2000                 7
2   209 09Jan2001   06Jul2000                 8
2       02Mar2001   06Jul2000                 9
2       06Mar2001   06Jul2000                10
2       06Mar2001   06Jul2000                11
2       06Mar2001   06Jul2000                12
2   203 06Mar2001   06Jul2000                13
2       18Apr2001   06Jul2000                14
2       18Apr2001   06Jul2000                15
2       18Apr2001   06Jul2000                16
2   183 18Apr2001   06Jul2000                17
2       02May2001   06Jul2000                18
2       07May2001   06Jul2000                19
2       08May2001   06Jul2000                20
2       17May2001   06Jul2000                21
2       31May2001   06Jul2000                22
2       31May2001   06Jul2000                23
2       31May2001   06Jul2000                24
2   83  31May2001   06Jul2000                25
```

And here is my current code. Sometimes the first record for an id (first.id) has missing value for ldl, so start_ldl is (.) which means nothing works moving forward from there forward (or the coding may be wrong overall!).

---

```
proc sort data=lab; by id date; run;                        

data labnew;
set lab;
by id;
retain start_dt ldl diff_ldl ;

IF FIRST.id THEN VISIT = 1;
ELSE VISIT + 1;

if first.id then start_dt=date;
else start_dt=start_dt;

if first.id then start_ldl=ldl;
else start_ldl=start_ldl;

yeardiff=floor((date-start_dt)/365.25);
diff_ldl=((ldl-start_ldl)/start_ldl)*100;

format start_dt date9.;
```

### run;

If anyone could advise on how I might code for this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Many thanks!

- Dee

Answer (score 1):

You want first non-missing ldl to carry forward, right?

Untested, would suggest:

```
data labnew;
  set lab;
  by id;
  retain start_dt start_ldl diff_ldl ;

  *initialize retained variables for each by group;   
  if first.id then do;
    visit=0;
    start_dt=date;
    start_ldl=.;
    diff_ldl=.;
  end;

  visit+1;
  if missing(start_ldl) then start_ldl=ldl; 

  yeardiff=floor((date-start_dt)/365.25);
  if n(ldl,start_ldl)=2 then diff_ldl=((ldl-start_ldl)/start_ldl)*100;

  format start_dt date9.;
run;
```

Comment: That will make diff_ldl=0 for the first visit that has an ldl value.  If you would rather diff_ldl be missing for that record, you can move the statement that assigns value to start_ldl to after the statement that assigns diff_ldl.